# Proving bump function is smooth in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, distribution-theory

> Let $B: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{C}; B(x) = \exp(\frac{1}{|x|^2-1})$ when $|x|<1$ and $B(x)=0$ when $|x|\geq 1$. Prove $B(x)$ is smooth.

Here's my idea. $B$ is radial so $B$ will be smooth on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ if $B$ is smooth in the case $n=1$. Hence, except for differentiability at the origin, we can assume $n=1$.

Now I can get this done with some tedious induction. Just wondering if there is a better way to go about this?
Many thanks!

Comment: Assuming $n=1$, don't we have an explicit formula for the Taylor Series of the exponential? Hence, $B(x)$ is real analytic and smooth.

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan. The problem is at $|x|=1$. For $|x|<1$ and for $|x|>1$ the function is clearly smooth, but at the border of these two regions, it might not be.

Comment: The biggest problem is at $|x|=1,$ not at $|x|=0.$ You need to show that $B^{(k)}(x)=0$ for all $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ when $|x|=1.$

Comment: First prove that $f(t) = e^{-1/t}$ for $t>0$ and $f(t)=0$ for $t\leq 0$ has $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k=0,1,2,\ldots$. Hint for this: $f^{(k)}(t) = p_k(1/t) e^{-1/t},$ where $p_k$ is some polynomial.

Comment: @ansdfkjdasnflkj Right, but if f is real analytic on $|x|<1$, then it has a complex analytic extension to an open set containing D. This extension is identically zero by assumption, hence it's analytic and $C^\infty$.